# L2 forwarding in DPDK

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to run the l2fwd DPDK application and I get the below output. I am not exactly sure what is happening here. For me all the values are 0, is it because I am not injecting any packets ? I see 16 ports and I dunno how these many ports come. I have only used 2 Ethernet ports.

[L2 forwarding image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IaC8u.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

l2fwd app works like a basic repeater, i.e. forwards all the frames from one port to another. So in order to get values other than zero, it is required to run an external packet generator.

Have a look at the l2fwd user guide for more details and some images with the required setup:
http://dpdk.org/doc/guides/sample_app_ug/l2_forward_real_virtual.html